# Cross Convert Currency in Sandbox PayPal out-of-date

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I use Sandbox PayPal now in order to test payments.
So, I am trying to use ConvertCurrencyRequest and it returns very-very old data.
Is it a bug of sandbox?

```
  curl  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: <MYDATA>" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: <MYDATA>" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: <MYDATA>"  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T"  -H "X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS: <MYDATA>"  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON"  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -X POST  -d '{"requestEnvelope" : {"detailLevel" : "ReturnAll","errorLanguage": "en_US"},"baseAmountList": [{ "currency" : { "code" : "USD", "amount" : "1" } }],"convertToCurrencyList": [{ "currencyCode" : "RUB" }]}'   https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/ConvertCurrency
```

This url returns

```
{"responseEnvelope":...,"estimatedAmountTable":{"currencyConversionList":[{"baseAmount":{"code":"USD","amount":"1"},"currencyList":{"currency":[{"code":"RUB","amount":"31.63"}]}}]}}
```

but,russian ruble costs about 50-66 RUB per USD at least 10 monthes.And more than 40 from Sept2014.Is this normal for Sandbox PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the database of currencies was frozen when created to reduce the amount of network resources required for the sandbox requirements. Sandbox environment is designed to test the implementation. After you see that the implementation works, switch to live credentials and you will get up-to-date information.